# How to download and install pip for python in two steps?

Tags: python, windows, pip, easy-install

I have a strange situation where I have a normal user account on windows where I have access to the internet and then an admin account without internet access.

Given this, how can I split the installation of easy_install and pip into two steps and get it installed on my machine?

Comment: How can you not have access to the internet as an admin? Just provide your user authentication to the proxy when logged in as admin.

Comment: 1. I have to explore that option.
2. I dont want the security group talking to me about some policy violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine as follows:

```
pip install -d <dir-name> <package-name>
pip install -f <dir-name> --no-index <package-name>
```

The 1st one will download the packages locally and the 2nd one will install them. Make sure you create the directory first.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the following:

- Download `get-pip.py` from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
- Run it using `python get-pip.py`

You're done!

Of course, with the latest version of Python, pip is included, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

That was simple.

Figured out that pip is installed automatically with python 2.10 and upgraded it to solve the problem!